# Using with gstreamer to stream to nginx, liquidsoap fill up memory and crash

Tags: gstreamer, rtmp, liquidsoap

Hi so as i say in title i am trying to use liquidsoap with gstreamer to stream dynamic playlist to rtmp server with nginx. Maybe this sound confusing, sorry english is not my native language.

Anyway everything works fine except after a while liquidsoap fill up all memory and swap of the server and crash without anything posted in log file.

The server have 16GB ram so it takes about 20hrs for liquidsoap to reach 30gb in size and crash.

I am using this as an example to stream.

```
#!/usr/bin/liquidsoap
set("frame.video.width", 1280)
set("frame.video.height", 720)
set("frame.video.samplerate", 25)
set("gstreamer.add_borders", true)

s = playlist.safe(mode="normal",reload=1,reload_mode="watch","/opt/playlist.m3u")

s = fallback([s, blank()])

s = video.add_image(
       width=150,height=58,
       x=10,y=10,
       file="/opt/logo.png",
       s)

  output.gstreamer.audio_video(
  video_pipeline=
    "videoconvert ! x264enc bitrate=2000 ! video/x-h264,profile=baseline ! queue ! mux.",
  audio_pipeline=
    "audioconvert ! voaacenc bitrate=128000 ! queue ! mux.",
  pipeline=
    "flvmux name=mux ! rtmpsink location=\"rtmp://192.168.1.1:1935/live/stream live=1\"",
  s)
```

Any ideas how is this happening and if i can somehow find a way to clean up memory usage after a while without having to restart the liquidsoap and stream? I guess even if i had 60gb ram on server, liquidsoap will fill that and crash eventually. Is this an old buffered videos in the file size?